# Can't get full html from webpage running Python Requests Get

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am writing a small web scraper to retrieve some information from several pages from a website.
I got stuck with the following error because the Get Requests does not retrieve the whole HTML code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    name = soup.find("div",class_="productTitle").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This is a snippet of the code:

```
URL_file = open('Continente_Links.txt', 'r+')
URL_list = URL_file.readlines()

for item in URL_list:

        results = requests.get(item, timeout=2.50, stream=True)
        print(results.status_code == requests.codes.ok)
        print(results.text)
        print(results.headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

        #name
        name = soup.find("div",class_="productTitle").text
        Title.append(name)
```

The first link contained in the [Continente_Links.txt](https://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?ProductId=4040367) file

Why is the Get Requests not getting the full HTML code?

Comment: They might be using js. You can do it with selenium library.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser'); print(soup.find("div",class_="productTitle").text)` prints `Papel Higiénico 4 Folhas Royal`

Comment: @AndrejKesely That is exactly what it is supposed to do! No idea why this is happening. Do you?

Comment: @FranciscoBorgesLeitão Maybe you get Captcha page after too many requests or the site has other protection.

Comment: @OsadhiVirochanaJayasingheSi @ AndrejKesely The code works fine outside the loop cycle, when inside the loop, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it because of js. I made code for **scraping** from selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

Title = []

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument('--headless') # comment this for turn off headless mode
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=firefox_options)

driver.get("https://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?ProductId=4040367(eCsf_RetekProductCatalog_MegastoreContinenteOnline_Continente)")
name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('productTitle').text
Title.append(name)
print(Title)
driver.close()
```